# ADO.NET как получить роль пользователя?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

Имеется база данных на Sql Server 2012, которая хранит пользователей различных ролей. На стороне клиента приложение на C#, подключается к sql server через SqlConnection(указывается строка подключения с логином и паролем пользователя). Подскажите как можно идентифицировать роль пользователя. Заранее благодарю.

Comment: Не понятно, речь идет о пользовательских ролях, которы реализуются например Asp Identity?

Comment: про роли на Sql Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это может помочь, если я правильно понял вопрос

```
SELECT p.NAME ,m.NAME FROM sys.database_role_members rmm
JOIN sys.database_principals p ON rmm.role_principal_id = p.principal_id
JOIN sys.database_principals m ON rmm.member_principal_id = m.principal_id
```

Comment: То что нужно, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Пример работы с ролями:

```
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;
using System;

public class A {
   public static void Main() {
      Server svr = new Server();
      Database db = new Database(svr, "TESTDB");
      db.Create();

      // Creating Logins
      Login login = new Login(svr, "Login1");
      login.LoginType = LoginType.SqlLogin;
      login.Create("password@1");

      Login login2 = new Login(svr, "Login2");
      login2.LoginType = LoginType.SqlLogin;
      login2.Create("password@1");

      // Creating Users in the database for the logins created
      User user1 = new User(db, "User1");
      user1.Login = "Login1";
      user1.Create();

      User user2 = new User(db, "User2");
      user2.Login = "Login2";
      user2.Create();

      // Creating database permission Sets
      DatabasePermissionSet dbPermSet = new DatabasePermissionSet(DatabasePermission.AlterAnySchema);
      dbPermSet.Add(DatabasePermission.AlterAnyUser);

      DatabasePermissionSet dbPermSet2 = new DatabasePermissionSet(DatabasePermission.CreateType);
      dbPermSet2.Add(DatabasePermission.CreateSchema);
      dbPermSet2.Add(DatabasePermission.CreateTable);

      // Creating Database roles
      DatabaseRole role1 = new DatabaseRole(db, "Role1");
      role1.Create();

      DatabaseRole role2 = new DatabaseRole(db, "Role2");
      role2.Create();

      // Granting Database Permission Sets to Roles
      db.Grant(dbPermSet, role1.Name);
      db.Grant(dbPermSet2, role2.Name);

      // Adding members (Users / Roles) to Role
      role1.AddMember("User1");

      role2.AddMember("User2");

      // Role1 becomes a member of Role2
      role2.AddMember("Role1");

      // Enumerating through explicit permissions granted to Role1
      // enumerates all database permissions for the Grantee
      DatabasePermissionInfo[] dbPermsRole1 = db.EnumDatabasePermissions("Role1");   
      foreach (DatabasePermissionInfo dbp in dbPermsRole1) {
         Console.WriteLine(dbp.Grantee + " has " + dbp.PermissionType.ToString() + " permission.");
      }
      Console.WriteLine(" ");
   }
}
```

Подробнее узнать можно [тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162144.aspx)